# Select all checkboxes in Angular/ JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I want to Select all checkboxes in Angular/JavaScript, I tried a few ways that didn't work.

the check code that is to select all is this one:

```
<div class="form-groupCheckbox">
    <input class="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="confirm1">  Selecionar todos  </label>
  </div>
```

I want to check all these boxes here when I click on the "select all" box

```
      <input class="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm1" type="checkbox">
      <label for="confirm1"> xx </label>


      <input class="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm2" type="checkbox">
      <label for="confirm1"> ff </label>

      <input class="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm3" type="checkbox">
      <label for="confirm1">rr </label>
```

Comment: Can you show us code you have written and tried to run when the Select All button is pressed?

Comment: When you are working with Angular, the best practice would be to define a component controller for your checkbox fields, loop through that to output the checkboxes, add a method for the "check all" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to link each of the checkboxes to some variable and then just make them all `true` when user select `select-all checkbox`.

**HTML file will look like this:**

```
<div class="form-groupCheckbox">
    <input class="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm1" type="checkbox" #selectAll (change)="onSelectAllChange(selectAll.value)">
    <label for="confirm1">  Selecionar todos  </label>
</div>

<ng-container *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxes">
  <input class="checkbox" name="confirm" [(ngModel)]="checkbox.value" id="{{checkbox.id}}" type="checkbox">
  <label for="confirm1"> {{checkbox.label}} </label>
</ng-container>
```

**TypeScript file will look like this:**

```
public checkboxes = [
    {
      value: false,
      id: 'checkbox_1',
      lablel: 'Label 1'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      id: 'checkbox_2',
      lablel: 'Label 2'
    },
    {
      value: false,
      id: 'checkbox_3',
      lablel: 'Label 3'
    }
  ];

  onSelectAllChange(value: boolean) {
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox: any) => {
      if (value) {
        checkbox.value = true;
      } else {
        checkbox.value = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way for javascript. Change main checkbox html as following.

```
<div class="form-groupCheckbox">
    <input class="checkbox" name="confirmmain" onclick="selects()" id="confirmall" type="checkbox">
    <label for="confirm1">  Selecionar todos  </label>
  </div>
```

Now add new script that makes checkbox check and uncheck

```
<script>
       function selects(){  
       var ele=document.getElementById('confirmall');  
       if(ele.checked == true) {
        
                var ele=document.getElementsByName('confirm');  
                
                for(var i=0; i<ele.length; i++){  
                    if(ele[i].type=='checkbox')  
                        ele[i].checked=true;  
                }  
       } else {
       var ele=document.getElementsByName('confirm');  
                for(var i=0; i<ele.length; i++){  
                    if(ele[i].type=='checkbox')  
                        ele[i].checked=false;  
                      
                }  
                }
            }         
      </script>
```